# Why user and account object is undefined in Next Auth callback

Tags: next.js, jwt, next-auth, libspotify

I was trying to console log session.user.accessToken and clientsecret which turned out to be undefined, so i headed towards NextAuth.js to see if there's problem, it seems account and user is undefined in jwt callback function

while `console.log(account)` which is undefined,were did i go wrong?

this is my [...Nextauth].js file

```
export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    SpotifyProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: LOGIN_URL
    })
    // ...add more providers here
  ],

  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  pages: {
    login: "/login"
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user, profile }) {
      //initial user sign in

      if (account && user) {
        console.log({ token, user, account, profile });
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: account.access_Token,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          username: account.providerAccountId,
          accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at * 1000 //handle expiry time in ms
        };
      }
      //return the previous token if current token is expired

      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires) {
        console.log("Existing token is valid");
        return token;
      }

      //refresh token
      console.log("Existing token has expired");
      return await refreshAccessToken(token);
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      session.user.username = token.username;
      return session;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can examine further in console.
For example, in [...nextauth].js add something like:

```
events: {
    signIn(message) {
      console.log('signin message', message)
    },
    session(){...},
    signOut(message) {
      console.log(message)
    },
  },

  // Enable debug messages in the console if you are having problems
  debug: true,
```

Reference: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events

Comment: still i can't see anything, i am not able to get accesstoken from account as it is undefined

Comment: I suggest adding:                                                                                                       
 jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
  }                                                                                                                                      SECRET would be different from JWT_SECRET in your case. Let see what follows first, and then discuss further.

Comment: more over: session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  }, should be present.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for jwt callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback):

> The arguments user, account, profile and isNewUser are only passed the first time this callback is called on a new session, after the user signs in. In subsequent calls, only token will be available.

You will only be able to access `user`, `account`, and `profile` at sign-in, so you would need to check if they are defined and use them to add whatever you need from them to the token, since subsequent calls to this callback (including `session` callback triggered by `getSession` or `getServerSession`) will only have the `token` available.